# Get checkbox list values to a single string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, checkboxlist

I'm trying to get checkbox list values to a single string. in ASP.net using C#.

Here's my code..    **I have  declared this globally.**

```
   string hobbies = "";
```

**This is the code to get the selected items to a string.**

```
   protected void chkListHobbies_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      for (int i=0;i<chkListHobbies.Items.Count;i++)
      {
         if (chkListHobbies.Items[i].Selected)
         {                
            hobbies += chkListHobbies.Items[i].Value + ",";
          }

    }
   hobbies = hobbies.TrimEnd(',');
```

**I'm displaying this on button click**

```
     protected void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
      Response.Write("Hobbies= "+hobbies);
     }
```

**It doesn't give the expected output.**
Would like to get this corrected if it's wrong or would like to know how to do it properly.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create hobbies list in your btnEnter_Click event handler because Asp.net webforms in stateless and you'll get a new hobbies variable after each postback. To address this issue you have to save hobbies state somehow (using viewstate or a hidden field) and use it later or as I suggested create hobbies list in btnEnter_Click.

Edit (examples):

1.Do the whole thing in btnEnter_Click:

```
protected void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      string hobbies = "";
      for (int i=0;i<chkListHobbies.Items.Count;i++)
      {
         if (chkListHobbies.Items[i].Selected)
         {                
            hobbies += chkListHobbies.Items[i].Value + ",";
          }

    }
   hobbies = hobbies.TrimEnd(',');
   Response.Write("Hobbies=" + hobbies);
```

2.Use ViewState:

```
private string hobbies
{
   get { return (ViewState["hobbies"] ?? "").ToString(); }
   set { ViewState["hobbies"] = value; }
}
```

and the rest of your code is exactly the same.